# Размещение файлов по папкам Pyinstaller

Tags: python

После того как pyinstaller соберёт приложение, в корневой папке много различных файлов/библиотек (python.dll и прочие)

```
dist/
/_socket.pyd
/*.exe
/python.dll
```

Хотелось бы разместить их вот таким образом:

```
dist/
/libs/_socket.pyd
/libs/python.dll
/*.exe
```

Т.е., чтобы все так называемые "потроха" лежали в отдельной папке.
Как осуществить желаемое?

Comment: Потроха и все бинарники вместе с python.dll засуньте себе в папку и укажите пути поиска модулей в sys при сборке! Это будет работать. У вас в папке останется только exe-шник и zip-архив с модулями.

Comment: @Xyanight , не понимаю "sys при сборке!" это получается нужно в *.spec указывать?
Я добавил папку "libs" в путь, через sys в программе. Да созданные мною модули читаются, однако например модуль socket и прочие стандартные библиотеки всё равно создают *.pyd в корневой папке билда. Как быть со стандартными библиотеками, мне их чего, все перенести в папку с проектом и потереть стандартные пути к ним?

Comment: В главном файле программы добавь import sys; sys.path.append("/путь/к/папке/libs"). И после сборки кидай туда все *.pyd и python.dll, кроме zip-архива с модулями.